# Command to execute a script later

Tags: linux, bash, sh, wait, execute

I would like to execute a script after 12 hours. I could execute the script by remote access, but problem is I will be travelling by flight and may not have internet access. So I was wondering if there is some command to execute a script after few hours or at some specific time. e.g.,

```
cat my_script.sh
echo Hello World
run my_script.sh at 23:00 hr
```

Comment: Take a look: `man at`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `cron` to add your script for a one-time run - http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: [cron](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/16f/notes/630_crontab_at_job_scheduler.html) is your friend

Comment: @Spade: Cron is exactly the wrong one for "a one-time run". Cron is great for a repetitive job.

Comment: @Cyrus, there is nothing wrong with using `cron`. In fact, the `at` command that you suggested is often not enabled by default on many systems. Also, my understanding was that `at` internally works through `crond` or `launchd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the man page for `at`

```
man at
```

There are lots of ways you can specify the time. You can do something like:

```
at -f my_script.sh 23:00
```

Answer (score 4):

Use cron job in linux.
like

```
0 */12 1 11 3 /bin/execute/my/script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
time.sleep(60*60*12)
# your script here

# for shell script:
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./my_script_name.sh'])
```

For anyone who doesn't have a ton of experience with shell scripts, make sure your .sh script has a shebang line at the top of the script 
`#!/usr/bin/env bash`
and that it's executable with `$ chmod 744 my_script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using either `cron` or `at` for this kind of operation.
If you need to run the job only one single time then `at` would be the most straightforward option.

If you prefer to run it on a recurrent basis/schedule (e.g. if you need it to run every night) it with more flexibility `cron` is the tool you are looking for.

Have a safe trip!